# Haskell - A better way of generating a new list (like folding) without folding

Tags: haskell

If `foldl` is given a function `(+)` and a list `[1..10]` it'll generate a final number.

---

What I want is given

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

output would be the Triangular Number series.

but given a list like

```
[3, 5, 1, 4, 7, 8, 10]
```

output would be

```
[3, 8, 9, 13, 20, 28, 38]
```

---

The way I'm doing that is generating a new list by using

`sum (take x) list`

where `x` is the current index

and appending it to the new list.

---

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: `[1..10]` wouldn't produce the Fibonacci sequence; it would produce a sequence of triangular numbers.

Comment: You're right, fixed the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at [PreludeList](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch9.html#x16-1720009.1), you'll notice function `scanl` right next to `foldl` (and `scanl1` to counter `foldl1`). Is that what you need perhaps?

```
Prelude> scanl1 (+) [3, 5, 1, 4, 7, 8, 10]
[3,8,9,13,20,28,38]
```

Though it would not generate Fibonacci out of positive integers.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the `scanl1` function:

```
> scanl1 (+) [3,5,1,4,7,8,10]
[3,8,9,13,20,28,38]
```